# Do faces with the same areas mean the same thickness?

Tags: modeling

I model a car rooftop, and I wanna have this rooftop with the same thickness. I wanna know: do faces with the same areas mean the same thickness of this rooftop? Please, help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not. You would have to measure the distance from the midpoint(center) of the top edge to the midpoint of the bottom edge.